Копирование выделенного текста (из браузера, текстового документа и т.д) без использования горячих клавиш и без имитации их нажатия
Собственно вопрос о заголовке, возможно ли подобное реализовать в c# или может в c++?
Сам в c# не разбираюсь, но написал скрипт на питоне, и хотел модулем импортировать подобную фичу себе в скрипт.
Несколько часов мучал нейросеть, но максимум что удалось, это скопировать название самого окна, а не выделенное мышью содержимое в нем.
Буду очень благодарен если поможете с готовым кодом.
На скриншотах то, что я имею ввиду под выделенным текстом



как в xorg, что ли? выделил текст - он попал в один из буферов обмена?

@aleksandr barakin не знаю что такое xorg, но суть в том, чтоб при копировании содержимого не спамить ctrl + c инпутами в клиент из которого содержимое будет копироваться.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server

операционная система какая? если Windows, то единственное то здесь можно придумать - это отправлять WM_COPY активному окну при отпускании левой кнопки мыши, которую надо будет хукнуть и постараться сделать так чтобы антивирус на кейлоггер не заорал. Сработает или нет - уже другой вопрос. Из минусов, при выделении чего-то мышкой, даже случайно, будет перетираться содержимое буфера. Чтобы при выделении клавиатурой такое же устроить, придётся очень сильно попотеть. Так как шифт зажимается не только для выделения, но и для печатания больших букв.

aepot система windows. а без лишних кликов не получится сделать? чтоб просто была функция копирования выделенного содержимого, которая будет вызываться в нужный момент и копировать необходимый текст?

Каких кликов, я же написал про отпускание левой кнопки. Зажали кнопку, выделили, отпустили, сработало копирование.

aepot дело в том, что текст ищет мой питоновский скрипт, сам я ничего мышью не выделяю.
нужна функция\модуль для этого скрипта, которая при вызове будет добавлять в буфер обмена содержимое на месте курсора, которое всегда по умолчанию является выделенным.
грубо говоря, нужен модуль\функция, которая будет делать то же самое, что keyboard.send('ctrl+c+')  из питоновской библиотеки (просто копировать в буфер обмена), только, при этом, делать это без использования хоткеев. если такое вообще возможно

Проще имитировать нажатие хоткеев после завершения работы скрипта (или что у вас предшествует копированию). Для винды есть куча разных библиотек компонентов и, не смотря на то, что любой визуальный компонент - это окно, набор событий у них будет разный. Прописывать логику для каждого типа, да еще и выяснить какой компонент в какой программе используется - слишком муторно и того не стоит.
